# DIV content not appearing with JQuery Cycle Plugin

Tags: jquery, css

I am working on a web site. This site will have multiple tabs. I want to use the JQuery Cycle plugin to bring the tabs in accordingly. Each of the tabs should take up the available area. In an attempt to do this, I've created the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html style="height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; color: #FFF;">
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
  <title>Index</title>

  <style type="text/css">                
    #content { height: 100%; overflow: hidden; background: white; }
    #header { float: left; width: 100%; background-color:silver; padding:8px 4px;}
    #tabItems { height:100%; }

    .tabItem { padding:15px; border:1px solid #ccc; background-color:blue; top:0; left:0; }
  </style>

  <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.5.3.js"></script>
  <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
  <script src="/Scripts/jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>
</head>

<body style="height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; color: #FFF;">

<div id="content">
    <div id="header">
        <a href="#" onclick="showTab(0);">Tab 1</a> | 
        <a href="#" onclick="showTab(1);">Tab 2</a> | 
    </div>

    <div id="tabItems">
        <div id="tabItem1" class="tabItem">
            <h2>Tab Content Number 1</h2>
        </div>

        <div id="tabItem2" class="tabItem">
            <h2>Tab Content Number 2</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#tabItems').cycle({
                fx: 'scrollDown',
                next: '#next',
                prev: '#prev',
                timeout: 0
            });
        });

        function showTab(tn) {
            $('#tabItems').cycle(tn);
            return false;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This code works fine IF I remove `#tabItems { height:100%; }`. When that style definition is there, I can't seem to flip between tabs. However, from what I know, I need that style definition in place to make each tab fill the remaining amount of real-estate. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I was checking this out - the code does actually work fine (in FF / IE at least) the tabs do cycle, the only difference with my code was I used the latest cycle JS from https://github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/jquery.cycle.all.latest.js

Was there a specific browser you couldn't see this working on?